# fair die is rolled until a number that has been obtained before is repeated

Tags: probability, dice

A fair die is rolled until a number that has been obtained before is repeated. Let the random variable X denote the number of rolls. Compute the probability
mass function of X.

Here's how I tackled this problem. Could you please check if this true? If it is not could you please hint

We have that supp(X) is {2,3,4,5,6,7}

Then P(X=2)=(6/6)(1/6)= 1/6 because we have 1/6 choices that we obtain the previous number.

P(X=3)=(5/6)(2/6)=10/36. Because 5/6 is the second roll where it is the probability that we do not land the first value of the roll and 2/6 is the probability that we land the first two values of the rolls.

P(X=4)=(5.4.3)/6^3

P(X=5)=(5.4.3.4)/6^4

P(X=6)=(5.4.3.2.5)/6^5

P(X=7)=(5.4.3.2.1.6)/6^6

Comment: This looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first evaluate $P(x=2)+P(x=3)+P(x=4)+P(x=5)+P(x=6)+P(x=7)$ and it is $1$. So it is probably correct.

If $P(x=2)+P(x=3)+P(x=4)+P(x=5)+P(x=6)+P(x=7)$ is not equal to $1$, then you must have calculated wrong.

This method can be used for checking.

Comment: A good first check and it might prove that the answer is wrong but it won't prove that it is right.  All $\frac{1}{6}$ also satisfies that.

Comment: @badjohn what do you mean by saying that it wont prove it right?

Comment: @ThePoorJew Suppose that I calculated it wrongly and found that each case had the probability of $\frac{1}{6}$ then it would pass Culver's test.

Comment: @badjohn I see. So what would be a better way to check then?

Comment: @ThePoorJew However, I agree with your calculation but that is because I agreed with your reasoning not just that it passes this test.

Comment: @ThePoorJew I am not aware of any definitive test to verify problems such as this.  If you want an example of how hard it can be then look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem, people argue a lot about that.  I suggest waiting a bit longer for other answers.